# How to increase KAFKA consumer on demand in single Group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Lets say we have one topic "topic-1" in kafka with partition 5. 
Consumer Group-A with 5 consumer attached to "topic-1" each partition. Due to large workload large number of message get publish. Now we want to scale up consumer / add more consumer in Group-A to process message.

How can we increase consumer ON_DEMAND in same group?
Is any way to do it from coding ? so that single message get consumed by each consumer.
Once load is decrease shut-down few consumer from same group.

Comment: Can anyone can suggest , how to monitor the kafka consumer is working properly or not. Any open source tools to do it.

Answer (score 0):

- What I would suggest is having some partitions as buffer for when the
  load increases.
- For eg. if having 5 partitions is enough for normal    load, I would
  suggest having 15 partitions for that topic but only 5 consumers
  for them at the start.
- Then, when the load increases, keep adding consumers, preferably in other machines, until the load decreases
- You can have kubernetes do the autoscaling for you

Answer (score -1):

Kafka framework suggest that the number of the consumers corresponds to the number of the partitions. Increasing the number of the consumers will not help as you will have one consumer per partition anyway and the rest will remain idle. If you need to speed it up you can read the data from Kafka and process them in another thread. You can scale with this number of processing threads and you will need to program it yourself.

Comment: In directly you are proposing that we can not increase the consumer count on demand.